# EDIT: how to use gzip instead of tar

Tags: linux, shell, gzip, gunzip

Edit- I want to use gzip, or gunzip since I am only zipping one file instead of tar. When I try to use gunzip it gives the following error:

```
gzip: /users/tnea01/logfile10.tar.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: /users/tnea01/logfile10.log: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

Here is the command I am running to find and gzip the log file:

```
find /users/tnea01/logfile10.log -type f -exec sh -c \ 'gunzip /users/tnea01/logfile_archive/$(basename $0)_$(date -r {} +%F).gz $0' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a compressed `.tar.gz` file, you also have to specify the compression type when unpacking. For GZip, use `z`, of Bzip2, use `j`. Just the same as when you create the file. Further, you seem to miss the "extract" option `x` that you should supply instead of the "create" (`c`) option:

```
tar -xzfv filename.tar.gz
```

Compared to creation using

```
tar -czfv filename.tar.gz files-to-add
```